# ASP 5 MVC 6 beta8, get Session using razor (better way)

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I write that code to retrieve session values

```
  @{
    var sessionName = new Byte[20];
    bool nameOK = Context.Session.TryGetValue("name", out sessionName);

    if (nameOK)
    {
        string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sessionName);
        <p> @result</p>
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to retrieve values( using less lines etc)

Answer (score 3):

A possible simplification:

At the top of your cshtml add

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
```

This gives access to the GetString method

```
Context.Session.GetString("test");
```

I'd imagine your code simplified can then look like

```
@{
    string sessionName = Context.Session.GetString("name");
    if (sessionName != null)
    {
        <p>@sessionName</p>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is explanation why .GetXYZ not working for me.

Comment: @firste You don't need `@` in  `@sessionName` if you are enclosing It inside `@{...}`. But good response as it helped me implement in my code. An upvote for that.